# Changing font size within declaration

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and I have an h3 class I am calling.  I want a smaller font size on a condition, but I want to use the same class, because I am using Google Fonts and it recognizes that class name... Is there any way to change font size within the class declaration?  Thanks.

```
$title = get_the_title(get_the_ID());
if(strlen($title) > 51){
//Want smaller font size for this one!
the_title('<h3 class="entry-title">', '</h3><br/>' );   
}else{
    the_title('<h3 class="entry-title">', '</h3><br/>' );
}
}?>
```

Comment: `<h3 class="entry-title" style="font-size: 11px">` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you want the same class then use style attribute with in h3tag it self as an inline style has come over external style

```
$title = get_the_title(get_the_ID());
if(strlen($title) > 51){
    //Want smaller font size for this one!
    the_title('<h3 class="entry-title" style="font- size:smaller;">', '</h3><br/>' );   
    }else{
        the_title('<h3 class="entry-title">', '</h3><br/>' );
    }
}?>
```